# Geopandas set geometry: ValueError for MultiPolygon "equal len keys and value"

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have 2 geodataframes with a geometry column and I copy some geometries from 1 to the other.

This works well with Polygons but returns a ValueError for any (valid) MultiPolygon.

Please advice how to solve this? I don't know if / how / why I should change the MultiPolygon to get "equal len keys and value"?

```
geodata01.loc[index, 'geometry'] = geodata02.loc[index, 'geometry']
```

This works well with Polygons. Only with MultiPolygons I get:

```
ValueError 
if len(labels) != len(value):
--> 611      raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
    612      'when setting with an iterable')
```

I also cannot do assignments of a buffered or simplified MultiPolygon either (the MultiPolygon is valid and I can plot, buffer, simplify but I cannot assign it):

```
geodata01.loc[index, 'geometry'] = geodata01.loc[index, 'geometry'].buffer(0)
#or
geodata01.loc[index, 'geometry'] = geodata01.loc[index, 'geometry'].simplify(tolerance=0)
```

This returns the same ValueError.

Comment: Hi Wouter, would you like to open an issue for this at https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues ?

Comment: Thanks Joris, I have done so: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/992

Comment: A MultiPolygon is basically a list of Polygons. Would it make sense for you to apply your processing on each of these Polygons when a MultiPolygon is detected? Basically: `list_of_polygons = list(Multipolygon)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explanation and workaround from the [github issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/992) as provided by Joris:

"The reason is that pandas checks the length of the value you want to assign, to see if it matches with the number of elements you are assigning to (here a single element, since the index is a scalar).
So we might need to discuss this on the pandas side how to deal with that.

As a work-around, you can assign to a list of one element:

```
df.loc[[0], 'geometry'] = df.loc[[1], 'geometry'].values
```

Note that I also use a list to select the single element I want to assign, but then do .values, so I am basically assigning an array of one value (the problem is when not converting to an array, pandas will try to align on the index, and the assignment goes wrong). "

Many thanks again to Joris who provided the workaround and created a pandas issue to resolve this: [REGR: assigning scalar with a length no longer works](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26333)

Comment: Hello ! Do you know why when I try this, I get this error ? "AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: @Elise1369: you can check the type of the object that you want to see the .values of (using type() ). My dataframe selection is using a list [] on the index. Yours may be a direct index which will return the single value (scalar) in this case a 'MultiPolygon' geometry object which does not have a values attribute.